# UIKeyboard with iPhone OS 4

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

Hi I have a big problem with iPhone 4.0 OS with this code

```
if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES) {
}
```

in condition UIKeyboard it not working. I try "UILayoutContainerView"
but it not working too.

please.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more information. What do you expect the result to be, what are you actually seeing as a result. Explain why it isn't working and what should happen when it should work.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the `description` method programmatically like that. It is used to show you a nice human-readable string in the console and when debugging. Apple could change the output of `description` at any time. Maybe you are looking for `isKindOfClass:`?

if ([keyboard isKindOfClass:[UIKeyboard class]]) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
- (BOOL) findKeyboard:(UIView *) superView; 
{
    UIView *currentView;
    if ([superView.subviews count] > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < [superView.subviews count]; i++)
        {

            currentView = [superView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"%@",[currentView description]);
            if([[currentView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
            {

                NSLog(@"Find it");

                return YES;
            }
            if ([self findKeyboard:currentView]) return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;

}

-(void) checkKeyBoard {
    UIWindow* tempWindow;

    for(int c = 0; c < [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]; c ++)
    {
        tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:c];
        if ([self findKeyboard:tempWindow])
            NSLog(@"Finally, I found it");  
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self performSelector:(@selector(checkKeyBoard)) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

And you also need to add this code to function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: I knew how to create custom keyboard. if anyone want to know please comment on this post ^__^

Answer (score 0):

```
@"<UIPeripheralHostView" will work instead of @"<UIKeyboard"
```

Dunno why.

Can you tell me then: How to determine the keyboard type in the UIKeyboard class?